# Calling Math functions from a separate class for calculations of a neural network causes net to not function properly

Tags: java, neural-network, data-storage

I have been following a tutorial on creating a simple 3-layer neural network, [which can be found here](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-and-implementing-neural-networks-in-java-from-scratch-61421bb6352c), my code is nearly one for one at the moment. In the tutorial, the calculations for their network are done in their "Matrix" class. While mine are being called from another class "Maths". Their example works, while mine does not. I am wondering why this is the case as it looks to me the it should work. For ease of looking up I'll include both the tutorial's class and mine.

Example code:

```
public class Matrix {
double[][] data;
int rows,cols;

public Matrix(int row, int col) {
    data = new double[row][col];
    rows = row;
    cols = col;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            data[i][j] = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
        }
    }
}        
public void add(Matrix B){
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            this.data[i][j] += B.data[i][j];
        }
    }
}

public static Matrix sub(Matrix A, Matrix B){
    Matrix temp = new Matrix(A.rows, A.cols);
    for (int i = 0; i < A.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < A.cols; j++) {
            temp.data[i][j] = A.data[i][j] - B.data[i][j];
        }
    }
    return temp;
}

public void multiplyElements(Matrix a){
    for (int i = 0; i < a.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.cols; j++) {
            this.data[i][j] *= a.data[i][j];
        }
    }
}

public void multiplyScalar(double a){
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            this.data[i][j] *= a;
        }
    }
}

public static Matrix DotProduct(Matrix A,Matrix B){
    Matrix temp = new Matrix(A.rows, B.cols);
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < temp.cols; j++) {
            double sum = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < A.cols; k++) {
                sum += A.data[i][k] * B.data[k][j];
            }
            temp.data[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }
    return temp;
}

public void Activate(){
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            this.data[i][j] = 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-this.data[i][j]));
    }
}

public static Matrix Transpose(Matrix A){
    Matrix temp = new Matrix(A.cols, A.rows);
    for (int i = 0; i < A.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < A.cols; j++) {
            temp.data[j][i] = A.data[i][j];
        }
    }
    return temp;
}

public static Matrix Clone(double[] A){
    Matrix temp = new Matrix(A.length,1);
    for(int i =0;i<A.length;i++)
        temp.data[i][0]=A[i];
    return temp;
}

public Matrix DxActivate(){
    Matrix temp = new Matrix(rows, cols);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            temp.data[i][j] = this.data[i][j] * (1 - this.data[i][j]);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

My Code:

```
public class Matrix {
double[][] data;
int rows, cols;
static Maths M = new Maths();

public Matrix(int row, int col) {
    data = new double[row][col];
    rows = row;
    cols = col;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            data[i][j] = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
        }
    }
}

public void add(Matrix B) {
    this.data = M.AddIndices(this.data, B.data);
}

public static Matrix sub(Matrix A, Matrix B) {
    Matrix temp = new Matrix(A.data.length, A.data[0].length);
    temp.data = M.SubtractIndices(A.data, B.data);
    return temp;
}

public void multiplyElements(Matrix B) {
    this.data = M.MultiplyIndexes(this.data, B.data);
}

public void multiplyScalar(double S) {
    this.data = M.MultiplyByScalar(this.data, S);
}

public static Matrix DotProduct(Matrix A, Matrix B) {
    Matrix temp = new Matrix(A.data.length, B.data[0].length);
    temp.data = M.DotProduct(A.data, B.data);
    return temp;
}

public void Activate() {
    this.data = M.ApplySigmoid(this.data);
}

public Matrix Transpose() {
    Matrix temp = new Matrix(this.data[0].length, this.data.length);
    temp.data = M.Transpose(this.data);
    return temp;
}

public static Matrix Clone(double[] A) {
    Matrix temp = new Matrix(A.length, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
        temp.data[i][0] = A[i];
    return temp;
}

public Matrix DxActivate() {
    Matrix temp = new Matrix(this.data.length, this.data[0].length);
    temp.data = M.Apply_dx_Sigmoid(this.data);
    return temp;
}
```

}

In each call to a function in M, the math class, the function will return a 2-d double array. And each function that is called is identical to the function in the example code except instead of creating a Matrix instance a 2d double array is created.

I believe that the issue is with how the data is being passed/stored, but this doesn't make particularly much since to me as a simple temp.data = returning array, should store it properly.

Thank you for any help or knowledge you can share.

EDIT:
I have found my issue, my dot product function was not working correctly.
Thank you

Comment: You know your Matrix class is not thread-safe, right?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you mean by thread-safe. And how would it being thread-safe effect this?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-does-the-term-thread-safe-mean-in-Java So as it exists, if for instance one thread has called add and another multiply, they could both be reading and changing values in a non-deterministic and incorrect way.